# Fine-tune selinux constraints on nginx without semanage?

Tags: nginx, selinux

I'm setting up nginx on a Rocky 8.9 server, and ran into SELinux problems trying to listen on ports other than 80 and 443.  The recommended solutions across the internet all seem to recommend semanage, which is provided by the policycoreutils-python-utils package, not present on this server.

Now, I can install the package, that's not particularly a problem, but it surprised me that SELinux itself seems not to have an inherent way to manage the constraints.  I'm used to having the kernel be tunable directly in various ways (e.g. sysfs).  Often I've seen optional packages which provide a more user-friendly face to things, but it's still always possible (in my previous experience) to manage things directly without needing to install any additional packages.

Is that not the case with SELinux?

The specific case in point here is wanting to allow nginx to bind to a couple of additional ports (in this case it's 162 and 5667).  Can this be done directly by changes to the contents of some files in /etc/selinux/ ?  I didn't find any details on how in my search.

Comment: I'm a little unclear on the question. Most subsystems in Linux require some sort of management commands -- netfilter has `iptables`, the networking subsystem has the `ip` command, the LVM subsystem has a whole suite of commands, etc. SELinux provides the `semanage` command. There is a sysfs filesystem `/sys/fs/selinux` through which you may be able to perform some tasks, but I haven't been able to find a lot of documentation on the sysfs interface.

Comment: @larsks, but with iptables, for instance, I have never run into a case where there was a *problem* caused by iptables, but NO firewall tool installed whatsoever (either iptables or firewalld).  Likewise with old cgroup v1, there was a commonly used set of management tools in "libcgroup", but you could also manage the cgroup mounts directly (and the interface was/is documented in kernel docs).  The aspect felt very new and alien to me here of "there is a problem caused by system X, so install this random python package to be able to manage the system X you already have."